# Building MAUI Android Failing

Tags: android, maui

I created a brand new MAUI app (I had to create a new app as the previous app I'd created with a preview version didn't work when I upgraded Visual Studio preview). This app is using prism.maui which shouldn't make any difference and I'm also using a class library built with the preview version.

My app runs fine with Windows so I have no concern that I have issues with the app. I have also cleared out the obj folder multiple times with no joy.

When I build Android I get the following error message:

> Error AMM0000
> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library D:\Code\AzureDevops\BootCom.Money.Xamarin\App\Money.App\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\lp\164\jl\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
> Money.App   D:\Code\AzureDevops\BootCom.Money.Xamarin\App\Money.App\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\AndroidManifest.xml    35

I know how to fix this - but even when I do I get a further issue:

> AMM0000
> Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
> is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:3-33:17 to override.
> Money.App   D:\Code\AzureDevops\BootCom.Money.Xamarin\App\Money.App\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\AndroidManifest.xml    24

I really don't know where to go from here. I've recreated this app now 3 times and if this is how it needs to work for MAUI I need to go back to using Xamarin.

Please help!

Comment: It says add in AndroidManifest `'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"'`

Comment: It does - but a) I have no idea how to do that in regards of is this an attribute of an existing node or do I need to create a new tag? and b) Everytime I rebuild it resets the whole thing and I have to change it all again.

Comment: It resets the whole thing? You mean the manifest xml in the obj folder? That is generated by merging the manifest xml in your Android folder (if any), with other stuff needed by Maui and other packages. Add to question the relevant part of the obj manifest. Should be possible to add to Android folder manifest. Need node at the same place in xml hierarchy, so show the full nesting of elements down to the mentioned line(s).

Comment: Yes, the exception I get is in the manifest file in the obj folders.

The issue here isn't just the fact this is breaking it's primarily the fact that this is breaking on a brand new app with no changes to any Android settings and this is the frustration.

Comment: Here is the manifest in the platforms folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="uk.co.bootcom.money" android:installLocation="auto">
 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="BootCom Money"></application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: The error indicates that you're still using `Android support library` , check the packages in your projects  to ensure all the libraries supports AndroidX .

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error after I added a package name via the properties of the project.

As a consequence of adding the package name via the options of the project, the AndroidManifest.xml package attribute was updated, wich is what is expected, but there was also a tag that was being added, wich was unwanted.
The tag was the following:

```
<uses-sdk />
```

After removing this tag everything worked again.

Comment: This is still the cause and the right solution in 2023 (VS 17.6.2 / .net7 ), ... could be releated with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11172

Comment: For me I removed that tag but it is always recreated by the program when I run it again and again. After that I went to the AndroidManifest file and I added minimum and target android version, in my program I set minimum to 30 and target to 31 and it is started to work well again

Comment: What's especially pathetic is that Microsoft's "bots" closed issue 11172 as well as 11682, both legit bug reports. But hey, at least an MS guy got to whine about "violations". SO comes through once again. Wish the OP would come back and accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to androidManifest.xml file
- add: uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" if not exist
  otherwise update uses-sdk section to uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
  That solves my problem