# uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion cannot be set to less than 21

Tags: android, maui

This is driving me crazy.

I have a MAUI project that sends the following error when compile:

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library

When I see the AndroidManifest.xml file, I see this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
```

I changed "19" by "21" and re-compile. It succeeds after that.

Then I change some code and compile again. Visual Studio sends the same error as before. I check that the "19" was set in that parameter again.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building MAUI Android Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454213/building-maui-android-failing)

Answer (score 6):

In my case with c# MAUI, I needed to remove this line from the AndroidManifest.xml in the Platforms/Android folder.

```
<uses-sdk />
```

Answer (score 0):

The official document about [Supported platforms for .NET MAUI apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms) said:

> .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) apps can be written for the
> following platforms:
>
> Android 5.0 (API 21) or higher.

So you can't make the value of `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion` lower than 21 in the maui project's android part. It's out of the .net maui support scope.

You can delete the `android:minSdkVersion` in the `<uses-sdk>` or delete the whole `<uses-sdk>` and it will keep the default value.

Comment: I deleted, but Visual Studio insists in adding it again as `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />`

Comment: Did you use any special nuget package? I never meet the problem that the VS adds `<uses-sdk>`in the AndroidManifest automatically. @jstuardo

Comment: I have installed CommunityToolkit, SimpleToolkit and UraniumUI besides the standard packages. How to know which package is responsible for this?

Comment: I have added the packages you said and all of them will not adds `<uses-sdk>` in the AndroidManifest automatically. Did you checked the AndroidManifest.xml file below the **\Platforms\Android** folder?@jstuardo

Comment: @jstuardo, did you manage to solve this issue? i am suffering exactly the same behaviour. my AndroidManifest.xml below \platform\android does not contain any number, just  <uses-sdk />

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>` in Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml solved the problem for me.
This is how my android manifest looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true">
            <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
            <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Milanov's answer worked for me.

I was having the same problem described by jstuardo.

First, if already open in VS, close AndroidManifest.xml while leaving the project open.  
Next, using Notepad or Notepads, open the version of AndroidManifest.xml found in 
      YourProject\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml 
Near the end you'll see:    <uses-sdk /> 
change it to:    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>
then save and close it. 
For me, after that VS started writing <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/> to the AndroidManifest.xml file each time and the project compiled without further errors.

[Note:  There may be many other AndroidManifest.xml files in your project under YourProject\obj\Debug\net7.0-android\lp...etc.  Many with the wrong min version.  Ignore them.  For me, just fixing the one mentioned before took care of everything.]
[Note 2:  Trying to fix it in any way using VS also didn't work.]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).